# R - why does str_detect return a different result than grepl when using word boundary on 'words' ending with dash

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, stringr

The help page for str_detect states "Equivalent to grepl(pattern, x)", however:

```
str_detect("ALL-", str_c("\\b", "ALL-", "\\b"))
[1] FALSE
```

While

```
grepl(str_c("\\b", "ALL-", "\\b"), "ALL-")
[1] TRUE
```

I imagine one of these is not working as intended? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if it is word boundaries because `str_detect("ALL-", str_c("\\b", "ALL", "\\b"))` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the argument `perl = TRUE` to `grepl()`, it gives the same result:

```
> grepl(str_c("\\b", "ALL-", "\\b"), "ALL-")
[1] TRUE
> grepl(str_c("\\b", "ALL-", "\\b"), "ALL-", perl = T)
[1] FALSE
```

This argument means `grepl()` will use Perl Compatible Regex.

There is this warning in `?grep`, which might be related?

> The POSIX 1003.2 mode of gsub and gregexpr does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., pattern = "\b"). Use perl = TRUE for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).